# How to use/import/install a Javascript/Typescript Package without NPM or Yarn?

Tags: javascript, typescript, open-source

To give some context, I am learning to work on Open Source software by looking at `Good first issues` in Open Source GitHub repositories. I have found an issue that I would like to work on and so I have downloaded the source code for an Open Source SDK and I am making changes in the SDK.

I want to be able to test my changes by writing another simple app using the SDK but I am not sure how to do this. Normally, if I were to want to use the current version of the SDK from the developer I would have Yarn or NPM install the package into my app and then import it using either `const package = require("package");` or `import package from "package"` depending on the requirement. This is where I am a little lost as instead of using something that is published I want to use my local version of the package to make sure that the changes I have made work as expected before creating a pull request.

Thank you in advanced for your advice.

Comment: You can give the path to the package you edited in `yarn add` or `npm install` command. `yarn add /path/to/package`. Probably the package must be built in order to be installed. Check the package's package.json file for any `build` command

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the directory of your SDK project and build a distributable version of your SDK.
2. Use `npm pack` or `yarn pack` to create a compressed package, usually it is a .tgz file.
3. Then you can use `npm install /project-path/your-sdk-version.tgz` or `yarn add file:/project-path/your-sdk-version.tgz`.
4. Once the package is installed, you can import it your package like you normally do.